# How to solve this system with Binomials?

Tags: equation-solving

I mean

```
{Binomial[x + 1, y]/Binomial[x, y + 1] == 6/5,Binomial[x, y + 1]/Binomial[x, y - 1] == 5/2}
```

Even

```
FindInstance[{Binomial[x + 1, y]/Binomial[x, y + 1] == 6/5, 
Binomial[x, y + 1]/Binomial[x, y - 1] == 5/2}, {x, y}, Integers]
```

fails.
Also I don't succeed in

```
FullSimplify[{Binomial[x + 1, y]/Binomial[x, y + 1] == 6/5, 
Binomial[x, y + 1]/Binomial[x, y - 1] == 5/2}, 
Assumptions -> x \[Element] Integers && y \[Element] Integers]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the binomials are expanded via `FunctionExpand` then the result is rational functions, which can be handled by `Solve`.

```
Solve[
 FunctionExpand[{Binomial[x + 1, y]/Binomial[x, y + 1] == 6/5, 
   Binomial[x, y + 1]/Binomial[x, y - 1] == 5/2}],{x,y},Integers]

(* Out[878]= {{x -> 8, y -> 3}} *)
```

Comment: Note: It's two equations in two variables, so exactly determined. The `Integers` domain is not strictly needed (it was added in an edit, not by me, and I do not take issue to the point of wanting to roll it back, just wanted to remark it is not so necessary here as one might guess).

Comment: "It's two equations in two variables, so exactly determined" - not necessarily.

Comment: Just pretend I wrote "generically"-- it's the generic assumption. Were it not exactly determined, then yes, dealing with the gcd would be a bona fide diophantine situation.

Answer (score 1):

NMinimize gives you a first real estimation

```
NMinimize[ {1, Binomial[x + 1, y]/Binomial[x, y + 1] == 6/5,Binomial[x, y + 1]/Binomial[x, y - 1] == 5/2 }, {x, y}] 
(* {1., {x -> 7.99973, y -> 2.99989}} *)
```

Unfortunately NMinimize forcing  `Element[{x, y}, Integers]` fails:

```
NMinimize[ {1, Binomial[x + 1, y]/Binomial[x, y + 1] == 6/5,Binomial[x, y + 1]/Binomial[x, y - 1] == 5/2 ,Element[{x, y}, Integers]}, {x, y}]
```

**EDITED:**

```
NMinimize[{1, Binomial[x + 1, y]/Binomial[x, y + 1] == 6/5, 
Binomial[x, y + 1]/Binomial[x, y - 1] == 5/2 && x > 0 && y > 0(* && 
Element[{x, y}, Reals]*)}, {x, y}]
{1., {x -> 8., y -> 3.}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your nonstandard approach. I think it is clear that integer solutions are required.

Comment: ContourPlot[{Binomial[x + 1, y]/Binomial[x, y + 1] == 6/5, 
  Binomial[x, y + 1]/Binomial[x, y - 1] == 5/2}, {x, 1, 20}, {y, 1, 
  10}] shows the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

`FindInstance` works fine:

```
FindInstance[{Binomial[x + 1, y]/Binomial[x, y + 1] == 6/5, 
Binomial[x, y + 1]/Binomial[x, y - 1] == 5/2 && 0 < x < 10 && 
0 < y < 10}, {x, y}, Integers]

(* {{x -> 8, y -> 3}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you. I treat as a bug that FindInstance[{Binomial[x + 1, y]/Binomial[x, y + 1] == 6/5, 
Binomial[x, y + 1]/Binomial[x, y - 1] == 5/2}, {x, y}, Integers] fails.

Comment: @user64494. I'm don't no .Possible yes it may be a bug.